# Scala -- Use evaluation of an expression to write dataframe to a csv file

Tags: scala, csv, dataframe, expression, eval

This is to use evaluation (Eval or something similar) of an expression (string) to write a dataframe to a csv file in Scala.

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession, SQLContext, Row, DataFrame, Column}
 import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
 import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
 import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror

 val df = Seq(("a", "b", "c"), ("a1", "b1", "c1")).toDF("A", "B", "C")
 val df_write = """df.coalesce(1).write.option("delimiter", "\u001F").csv("file:///var/tmp/test")"""

 // This is one of my failed attempts - I have tried using the interpreter as well (code not shown here).    
 val tb = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()  
 toolbox.eval(toolbox.parse(df_write))

 Errors are: 
 object coalesce is not a member of package df ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shiva, try the below code. The issue was that the object variables were not in scope for the toolbox and therefore it was unable to evaluate the expression.

```
package com.mansoor.test

import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

object Driver extends App {

  def evalCode[T](code: String): T = {
    import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
    import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => m}
    val toolbox = m.mkToolBox()
    toolbox.eval(toolbox.parse(code)).asInstanceOf[T]
  }

  val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("Test")
    .master("local[2]")
    .getOrCreate()

  import sparkSession.implicits._
  val df: DataFrame = Seq(("a", "b", "c"), ("a1", "b1", "c1")).toDF("A", "B", "C")

  val df_write =
    s"""
       |import com.mansoor.test.Driver._
       |
       |df.coalesce(1).write.option("delimiter", "\u001F").csv("file:///var/tmp/test")
       """.stripMargin

  evalCode[Unit](df_write)

  sparkSession.sparkContext.stop()
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  All the imports were done, and it is possible to write the dataframe to csv as you have identified...   However, the requirement is to be able to evaluate a string, and have that write a dataframe into a csv...

Comment: Thanks, once again.  Is it possible to have a function that extends scope to within the string... or an alternate approach?

Comment: @Shiva could you elaborate your question...do you want to call a function within the string (or) you want to declare a function within the string and use it further.

Comment: Instead of having an object, it would be preferable to call a function that addresses the scope of the toolbox from within the string (if possible)...